# Why is Firefox ignoring 'unsafe-inline' csp directive?

Tags: javascript, firefox, content-security-policy

Using Firefox 69.0.1.

In a local HTML file I want to run a JavaScript script in a `<script>` tag. However, even after adding

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
```

to the HTML header, Firefox still complains as follows:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).
```

The line associated with the error is the line containing the opening `<script>` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" />
<head>
    <title>Title</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script>
        console.log("Foo, bar!");
    </script>

</head>

<body>Nothing interesting</body>

</html>
```

This is working in Chrome. What's up, Ff? Why you so mean?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NoScript and forgot to enable the scripts from your site? This same error would occur in this case.

Also, you may wish to use a more extensive policy like:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```